# Error while connecting to a database: "Invalid Datasource"

Tags: mysql, jndi, pentaho-report-designer

I'm working in Pentaho Report Designer 5.2. While trying to connect to a MySQL database using JNDI I'm facing an error saying `Invalid data source:'openflights'`
but there exist a table "openflights" in my database.

Help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!
[image: Error screenshot]

Here is the JNDI Configuration

```bash
#MySQL - openflights
openflights/type=javax.sql.DataSource
openflights/driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
openflights/user=pentaho_user
openflights/password=password
openflights/url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openflights
```

[image: Table openflight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you defined the JNDI details?

change DRIVER value to **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

add JNDI in "C:\Users{YOURUSER}.pentaho\simple-jndi\default.properties" then stop the bi server and lauch again

Comment: Even after changing the Driver value to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", it's giving me the same error as mentioned previously.

Comment: please tell me, where you have defined the JNDI details? which file, also are you using the CE?

Comment: "C:\prd-ce-5.1.0.0-752\report-designer\configuration-template\simple-jndi\default.properties", I have changed the JNDI in "default.properties" file

Comment: add JNDI in "C:\Users\{YOURUSER}\.pentaho\simple-jndi\default.properties"

then stop the bi server and lauch again

Comment: Hey Thanks alot, it did that thing, now the JNDI is working fine, and is it that always I have to add JNDI details in this location file only..Much more thanks

Comment: Thanks :) i ran into this situation myself few days back.

Comment: I only added JNDI to above mentioned file in .pentaho directory, i did'nt add it in "C:\prd-ce-5.1.0.0-752\report-designer\configuration-template\simple-jndi\defaul‌​t.properties"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108940/discussion-between-deepesh-and-shzyincu).